# espeak ouputs no sound when ran from script running in the background

Tags: cron, espeak

I have a cron job running a script every hour. The script contains this espeak entry:

```bash
espeak -v mb-fr1 -s 120 "Snapshot" --stdout | paplay
```

When the shell script is run normally in a shell, espeak speeches well. However, when the script is started from my cron job, everything works fine but espeak, which outputs no sound. Is there a way to redirect `--stdout` to the Desktop environment… (I can't express otherwise)

Comment: You may just be missing some environment variables. Try `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 paplay` if your id is 1000.